# Get metadata from file not created by Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Google Apps Script, that fetches the version number of a single file. Basically to monitor if the file was changed/opened, etc.
I want to do this by just using the `drive.file` API, to avoid having to go through the security assessment check, which becomes necessary (?) when using restricted access APIs.

I got it working if I create the file directly in the GAS but couldn't figure out how to get the metadata from user-created files.

This is the code (super-simple, though):

```
function myFunction() {
  var test = {
   title: 'myFile',
   "parents": [{'id':"[ID]"}], 
   mimeType: 'text/plain'
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(test);
  file_id = file.getId();
  i = 0;
  while (i<5) {
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    output = Drive.Files.get(file_id).version;
    Logger.log(output);
    i += 1;
  }
}
```

The APIs are set in the appsscript.json file via:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Is there any way to achieve getting this info without full API access to the user's Google Drive?
Your help is much appreciated!
- Fabian

Comment: *Is there any way to achieve getting this info without full API access to the user's Google Drive?* Are you asking how to access any file in Google drive without permission to access all of Google drive  permission?

Comment: No, I am asking how to access a file that the user created via my mobile app and that is monitored within his own account. If the file is changed outside of the mobile app, the user should be notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google picker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) to let the user choose what file he may share with  your project with no more permissions than the ones listed in the question.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for that! I didn't know about this possibility.
I will look into this.

Comment: I played around with Picker and managed to select a file without giving access to the whole Google Drive. 
However, I couldn't get the version number of the selected file by calling Drive.Files.get(id), even though I set the Drive API permission. 
Do you happen to know what the reason could be? I am still new to this so I have difficulty knowing where to look.
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Fabian I'm not sure. Kindly post a new question with error details and [mre] so that others may be able to research your problem. EDIT: On second thought you may need to use `Urlfetchapp` to access the api instead of  advanced Google services.

Comment: Alright, I will do that. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Fabian If it's relevant, the pickerCallback also provides [`Document.LAST_EDITED_UTC`](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#Document)

Comment: Thanks for the input. This API call doesn't work in my case as a preview of the selected file doesn't change the "last edited UTC" value. What I need is really the info that somebody touched the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drive.metadata.readonly`, or `drive.metadata` scope. Of course you need at least read access to that file.

```
var params = {
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    includeTeamDriveItems: true
  };

  params.fields = 'modifiedDate, version';
  var modTime = Drive.Files.get(fileId, params);

  Logger.log(modTime);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry for the late reply! 
`drive.metadata.readonly` seems to become a restricted scope API next year. 
If I used that API, a security assessment seems to become necessary which apparently costs $15.000 which I can not pay.

Comment: Where did you read that? I couldn't find anything regarding an oncoming update of those scopes in the documentation.

Comment: I read it here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en under Restricted Scope App Verification